# Ask for help on how to get all the filtered list from specific array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an object in an array called "Person".
Within the object "Person", there is an array called "info".
My goal is to get all the values with the prefix "age:" in an array "info" when filtering by "gender:male". So, my desired output will be 1 to 9 because I want also to remove duplicates.

Below is my code but the results are only two values (1 and 4). Maybe the output is one value per person.
I spent a lot of hours playing the code but no luck. That's why I bring my problem here hoping anybody who is an expert on this can help me.

```
<script>
var array = [
                {
                    "person": {
                        "info": [
                            "age:1",
                            "age:2",
                            "age:3",
                            "age:4",
                            "age:5",
                            "age:6",
                            "gender:male"
                        ]
                    },
                    "person": {
                        "info": [
                            "age:4",
                            "age:5",
                            "age:6",
                            "age:7",
                            "age:8",
                            "age:9",
                            "gender:male"
                        ]
                    },
                    "person": {
                        "info": [
                            "age:8",
                            "age:9",
                            "age:10",
                            "age:11",
                            "age:12",
                            "age:13",
                            "gender:female"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
            var filteredAges = [];
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var infoGroup = array[i].person.info,
                    ageGroup = [];
                    for (j = 0; j < infoGroup.length; j++) {
                        ageGroup.push(infoGroup[j]);
                        var ageInfo = ageGroup.find(ages => ages.includes('age:'));
                    }; 
                    if (ageInfo) { 
                        if (filteredAges.indexOf(ageInfo) == -1) { 
                            filteredAges.push(ageInfo)
                         }         
                      } 
              }

            for (i = 0;i < filteredAges.length; i++) {
                console.log(filteredAges[i]);
            }
</script>
```

Comment: The `find` method returns the _first_ element of the array, that satisfies the condition. You start by sticking `age:4` into your array `ageGroup`, then you go and find the first element of that array, that contains `age:`. Next iteration - you push `age:5` into your array, your array now contains `age:4`, `age:5`. Now you go looking for the first element that contains `age:` again … which is, of course, still `age:4`.

Comment: You are correct. The cause of my issue is the find(). I replaced it with filter() and it is now working.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Seems like all your object keys are just `person` i.e

```
[
 {
  person: {...},
  person: {...},
  person: {...}
 }
]
```

So when the variable `array` is evaluated it just has one person

You need to restructure your data maybe like below or something similar

**Example - 1**

```
[
 { person: {...} },
 { person: {...} },
 { person: {...} },
]
```

**Example - 2**

```
[
 [ { person: {...} } ],
 [ { person: {...} } ],
 [ { person: {...} } ]
]
```

After fixing this you can try debugging your problem

If you want to get all items in `info` array that has `"age:"`

you can use `filter` like this

```
const ageInfos = [
                  "age:8", "age:9", 
                  "age:10", "age:11",
                  "age:12", "age:13",
                  "gender:female"
                 ].filter(x => x.startsWith("age:"))
```

Your output - `ageInfos` will be

`["age:8", "age:9", "age:10", "age:11", "age:12", "age:13"]`

You can also use `Set` to only collect unique strings or just push everything to an array and later use `Set` to return only unique values like this

```
const arrayWithDuplicates = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];

const unique = [...new Set(arrayWithDuplicates)];

console.log(unique); // unique is ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON is wrong. You just overright person object.
Data structure is really awful, I would recommend you to rethink it.

Assuming person will not be overwritten I came up with this solution.

```js
var array = [
            {
                "person": {
                    "info": [
                        "age:1",
                        "age:2",
                        "age:3",
                        "age:4",
                        "age:5",
                        "age:6",
                        "gender:male"
                    ]
                },
                "person1": {
                    "info": [
                        "age:4",
                        "age:5",
                        "age:6",
                        "age:7",
                        "age:8",
                        "age:9",
                        "gender:male"
                    ]
                },
                "person2": {
                    "info": [
                        "age:8",
                        "age:9",
                        "age:10",
                        "age:11",
                        "age:12",
                        "age:13",
                        "gender:female"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]


        let agesArray = []
        let ages = []
        array.forEach((peopleObj) => {
            for (const index in peopleObj) {
                ages = peopleObj[index].info.map((age) => {
                    const ageNumber = age.split(':')[1]
                    if (parseInt(ageNumber)) {
                        return ageNumber  
                    }
                }).filter(val => !!val)
                agesArray = [...agesArray, ...ages]
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. I'll apply all of your ideas and try if it can solve my problem.